# Python algorithm output troubleshoot

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, output

I have attached a python 2.7 script to answer question number 2 from the following link: http://labs.spotify.com/puzzles/

My attempt to solve is currently being met with a "wrong answer" reply, yet my code successfully works for the sample inputs on the site. I have tried modifying it to return and even print a list of the top m songs, instead of printing them out individually, but that did not work either. Any help or ideas would be great. Thanks in advance

```
import sys

def main():

    line1 = sys.stdin.readline().split()
    total_songs = int(line1[0])-1
    num_songs_return = int(line1[1])

    data = sys.stdin.read().split()

    while(total_songs >= 0):
        data[2*total_songs]= float(data[2*total_songs]) * (total_songs+1)
        total_songs-=1

    answers = [(data[a], data[a+1]) for a in range(0,len(data),2)]
    answers.sort(reverse=True)
    for n in range(num_songs_return):
        print answers[n][1]

main()
```

Comment: It might help to look at solutions that have been accepted—people post these all over the web—and see what they're doing differently. For example, here's [one I found at GitHub](https://github.com/alonsovidales/spotify-puzzles-v2/blob/master/zipfsong/zipfsong.py). If you can't understand his code (which is a bit over-engineered and over-complexified…), you can add some debugging output to both and see how his intermediate data compare to yours.

Comment: I notice that your solution is for Python 2.7, but the problem page specifically says "Python (version 2.6)". So, the first thing to do is make sure your code doesn't do anything 2.7-specific. I don't see anything, but better to test it than to just visually spot-check it, obviously. Also, you might want to try using `raw_input()` instead of `sys.stdin.readline()` and `sys.stdin.read()`. There could be a bug in their test harness (after all, there was one before, according to the code I linked above) which they've worked around for `raw_input` but haven't (yet?) for `sys.stdin`.

Comment: For that matter, how do we even know they fixed the bug that alonsovidales saw? Try just submitting his answer (with some comments explaining what you're doing) to see if it actually passes. If not, write to the judges and ask them to look at your own answer as well.

Comment: Took your advice and resubmitted the script that alonsovidales submitted and it passed. Best way to test it's not 2.7 specific? I'm also not quite sure how to integrate the raw_input() into my current code as an equivalent for what it's currently doing.

Comment: The best way to check it's not 2.7 specific is to run it with 2.6. If you can't install 2.6 alongside 2.7 (if you're on a Mac, you already have it; otherwise, you probably don't) or install a VM, there are a dozen or more web-based online Python interpreters you can use. Or you could let me test it… I ran it on 2.6 on my Mac, and it's fine.

Comment: As for `raw_input()`, it's basically like using `sys.stdin.readline()`  except that (a) it strips the trailing newline, and (b) it raises `EOFError` at EOF instead of returning an empty string.